# Opera in 16-04 Missing Opera button to set preferences

Tags: 16.04, opera

I have downloaded the latest stable version for 16-04, according to my Terminal.[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eR1mB.png) Where is the Opera button?  I know there should be an Opera button in the top left of the browser so I can set preferences.  Not there.  Has anyone any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The page you are looking at on the screen-shot is an old version of Opera with a totally different user interface.

The Opera version you are using does have a button in most desktop environments, but in Unity, which is what you are using, there are regular menus instead. Hover with the mouse over the title ("Getting started with Opera - Opera"), and the menus will be revealed.